# How do I use the Loopback where filter correctly on REST-API

Tags: loopback

Hi there I seem to miss some information about Loopback where clause or syntax. My problem is, that I receive an empty array if I try to get a list of matching model instances, does no difference if in loopback api explorer or trhough http api request.

My "subject" model:

```
[
  {
    "user": "string",
    "semester": "string",
    "subject_name": "string",
    "subject_relevance": 1,
    "subject_details": 0,
    "id": "string"
  }
]
```

One Instance of Subjects:

```
{
  "user": "59eef907cc199c1cf8f99296",
  "semester": "59eef6f8ebf12e1a37ee898b",
  "subject_name": "Mathematik",
  "subject_relevance": "1",
  "subject_details": "",
  "id": "59eef96aebf12e1a37ee898f"
}
```

My Loopback API Explorer filter:

```
{"where" : {"semester" : "59eef6f8ebf12e1a37ee898b"}}
```

My http request:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/subjects?filter[where][semester]=59eef6f8ebf12e1a37ee898b
```

The result I receive:

```
[]
```

If I try to search for this:

```
{"where" : {"subject_name" : "Mathematik"}}
```

or in browser:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/subjects?filter[where][subject_name]=Mathematik
```

I reveive the instance correctly or as expected. So I went thrugh the [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Where-filter.html) and I strugle to find some hints or solutions to my problem. Can someone help me out or suggest me something to get the right instance back? Do I miss something? Has it to do that these are ID-fields or what is it?

Thanks for any help in advance!!

Comment: this is strange it should be consistent , i have never faced this

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to get your records based on where clause

one is by using 'findOne' method

*get request*

```
http://localhost:3000/api/subjects/findOne?filter[where][semester]=59eef6f8ebf12e1a37ee898b
```

Other one is using normal get request

```
http://localhost:3000/api/subjects?filter={"where":{"semester":"59eef6f8ebf12e1a37ee898b"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using loopback 4 and I had faced the same issue.
[Here is the issue in loopback git](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3593)

Solution is the add this setting in your @model decorator

```
@model({settings: {"strict":false, "strictObjectIDCoercion": true}})
```